# How to populate SOAP header Sales Force

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, apex-code

I created a service webservices in Saels Force, from the class created soliceitei generation of WSDL and went to the company that will consume the service. However there are some header information that can not preecher, someone could help me?

```
  <soapenv:Header>
  <atu:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
     <atu:allowFieldTruncation>???????????</atu:allowFieldTruncation>
  </atu:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
  <atu:DebuggingHeader>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <atu:categories>
        <atu:category>??????????</atu:category>
        <atu:level>???????????</atu:level>
     </atu:categories>
     <atu:debugLevel>????????????</atu:debugLevel>
  </atu:DebuggingHeader>
  <atu:CallOptions>
     <atu:client>??????????????</atu:client>
  </atu:CallOptions>
  <atu:SessionHeader>
     <atu:sessionId>?????????????</atu:sessionId>
  </atu:SessionHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the session Id, you will have to login using the login method provided by Enterprise.WSDL or Partner.wsdl.

Below is a soap of exeplo filled with the header.

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <atu:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
     <atu:allowFieldTruncation>**true**</atu:allowFieldTruncation>
  </atu:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
  <atu:DebuggingHeader>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <atu:categories>
        <atu:category>**Apex_Code**</atu:category>
        <atu:level>**Debug**</atu:level>
     </atu:categories>
     <atu:debugLevel>**Debugonly**</atu:debugLevel>
  </atu:DebuggingHeader>
  <atu:CallOptions>
     <atu:client>**true**</atu:client>
  </atu:CallOptions>
  <atu:SessionHeader>
     <atu:sessionId>**YOUR_SESSION_ID**</atu:sessionId>
  </atu:SessionHeader>
```

I hope that helped.